# Intellij doesn't navigate to the code lines in the stack trace for locally build/installed sources

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stack-trace

I use a locally built `eclips.jdt` in my project. I use the command `mvn -P build-individual-bundles package` to build the package locally and installed the created jar file using `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/location/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.24.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=org.eclipse.jdt -DartifactId=org.eclipse.jdt.core -Dversion=3.24.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true`

Currently, I have a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that's firing from the locally built `eclips.jdt`. The stack trace given in the IDE doesn't go to the correct code line in `eclips.jdt` or some code links are not clickable either. But I observed that this does not happen for the jars that I downloaded from the maven central repository. This happens only for the locally built jars.

I further noticed that when I add a debug point to the `JavaASTUtil.java:89`, the debugger does not step into the code lines that are in the locally built jars either.

Does anybody have an idea about this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Where does it navigate on click? Are the classes in sync with the sources attached to this library?

Comment: Thanks, For example, DiagnoseParser.java:254 navigates to the line 254 but that line has just a bracket. The link Parser.java:12922 goes to the beginning of the file Parser.java, the file Parse.java has lines fewer than 12922. I think it is sync, I can see the changes that I have done in eclips.core through my project (decompiled classes).

Comment: Does it navigate to the attached source file or to the decompiled code? If it's the source file, what's the location of this .java file on disk?

Comment: It navigates to the decompiled code in local maven repository.

Comment: `/location/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.24.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` or some different file?

Comment: It's same file but different location, `/location/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.24.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is the file that I installed to local maven repo. When I click, it decompiled the  installed code in local maven repo. The opened file located in  `.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.24.0-SNAPSHOT/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.24.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Are these files exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. The decompiled code contains the changes that I did for the `/location/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.24.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Comment: I can only suggest debugging the class loaders to see from where the .class file with the different line numbers is loaded. Note that if there is any annotation processing/obfuscation applied during the build, it may also break the line numbers for the debugger.